# How to prove that for $x,y>0$, the inequality $|x-y|\leq \max\{x,y\} \left|\log x-\log y\right|$ holds?

Tags: inequality, logarithms

I am reading a paper and it states the following inequality. It appears to look trivial but I am struggling to show it.

Is it the following:
For $x,y>0$, we have $$|x-y|\leq \max\{x,y\} \left|\log x-\log y\right|.$$ Does anyone have any hints/idea how to proceed?

Comment: have you tried the mean value Theorem?

Comment: Yep, this also works, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a second way. WLOG,  assume $x < y $.  Then

$$y-x = \int_x^y dt = y\int_x^y {dt\over y} \le y\int_x^y {dt\over t}
= y(\log(y) - \log(x)).$$

Comment: Probably my favourite method, thanks.

Comment: Small typo: you're missing a $y$ before the second integral.

Comment: I inserted the rogue y.

Answer (score 3):

*Maybe not the most elegant: but well, it gets the job done without too much thinking.*

If $x=y$, then we are done. Without loss of generality, assume $x>y>0$.

We want to show that
$$
x - y \leq x \log\frac{x}{y}
$$
so that it's sufficient to show that the function (once $y$ is fixed) $f_y\colon x> y \mapsto  x \log\frac{x}{y} - (x-y)$ is non-decreasing (as $f_y(y)=0$).

It is differentiable, and $$f_y'(x) = \log x -\log y \geq 0$$
for all $x>y$, leading to the conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

W.L.O.G we can say $x>y$
then we get $$1/x<\frac{\log{x}-\log{y}}{x-y}$$
now consider $f(x)=\log{x}$ thus $f'(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ and as we can say $f'(x)$ is always decreasing and our R.H.S is nothing but slope of a line segment which will be higher in magnitude than our L.H.S